# Selectively deleting system scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Windows 7 box has a list of scheduled tasks - > Default Windows tasks + Certain custom tasks that all start with a certain string. Previous code deleted all tasks with the command:

```
schtasks /Delete /TN * /F
```

Instead we want to retain the default Windows tasks, and selectively delete the tasks that start with a certain string say `abctask1`, `abctask2`. How to proceed further? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using something like `schtasks /Delete /TN abctask* /F`?

Comment: Doesnt work. I think the * wildcard doesn't work as expected.

Comment: If the wildcard doesn't work properly in that manner, your best bet might be to obtain the list of tasks with the `/query` option, loop through them finding the ones that match your desired pattern, and kill them off using their full names. Something like a Perl script might be best for this kind of task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your tasks are one word (e.g., abctask1, abctask2 - not "abc task 1"), this should work:

```
for /f %%x in ('schtasks /query ^| findstr abctask') do schtasks /Delete /TN %%x /F
```

Comment: I would imagine that `find`, being less than 1/4 the size of `findstr` would react faster. Also, both support the use of quotation marks to surround the search term (`find` requires them), doing that will allow finding tasks like the "abc task 1" you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Mark, well actually it did not accept %%x, I changed it to %x and it worked! :) Cheers! :)

Comment: @user1620230 I assumed you were running this in a batch file.  The double-percents in %%x are required in a batch file, whereas %x is required at the command line.

@JamesK, I think you'd be very hard pressed to find any real-world speed difference in `find` vs. `findstr`, particularly in something this small. :-)

Comment: Aha, got you :) Well yes ultimately it might be used in a batch script. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: schtasks /query truncates task names to 50 characters. The /xml option avoids truncation. `for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('schtasks /query /xml ^| findstr taskname') do `

Comment: I was running in the command prompt so I needed to change this to use just a single %. Apparently the %% is used for a batch file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want wildcard (*) to be used in your selection of tasks to delete, try using this simple batch command:

(sample only)

```
echo off
del %SystemDrive%\Windows\Tasks\Google*
del %SystemDrive%\Windows\Tasks\Facebook*
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here while looking for a way to automate disabling some stock Windows scheduled tasks. I could not get any of the current examples to properly handle task names with backslashes and spaces. I found that using csv format and the find command worked best for me:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%x in ('schtasks /query /fo csv ^| find "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\"') do schtasks /Delete /TN %%x /F
```

Answer (score 2):

You guys have helped here quite a bit.  While the above works for the shorter names and 'user3490' posted quite a nice addition to the string, it still did not seem to work with names with spaces.  I found using wildcards with SCHTASKS work with '.' rather than '*' and found an interesting modification to the string allowing much needed opportunity!  I'll paste below examples of what I used in a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%x in ('SCHTASKS /QUERY /FO:LIST ^| FINDSTR "AVGPCTuneUp_Task."') do SCHTASKS /DELETE /F /TN "\%%x"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%x in ('SCHTASKS /QUERY /FO:LIST ^| FINDSTR "AMD.Updater."') do SCHTASKS /DELETE /F /TN "\%%x"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%x in ('SCHTASKS /QUERY /FO:LIST ^| FINDSTR "Lenovo.Smile."') do SCHTASKS /DELETE /F /TN "\%%x"
```

Thank you all here for the excellent pointers!  I am aware this topic is over a year old, but I hope this helps someone else who may have not gotten this far.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer works fine as long as you have fairly short scheduled task names, but the default output of `schtasks /query` (table format) truncates the task names to 32 characters, which causes errors when trying to delete them.

If you need to deal with tasks that have longer names, I would recommend using list output format instead, which does not truncate:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%x in ('schtasks /query /fo:list ^| findstr abctask') do schtasks /Delete /TN %%x /F
```

If the tasks you want to delete have a common prefix, you can further refine the match from findstr:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%x in ('schtasks /query /fo:list ^| findstr ^^abctask') do schtasks /Delete /TN %%x /F
```